# radio button custom image not changed below lollipop

Tags: android

i have problem where custom image for radio button not worked below lollipop:

first of all i create style like below

```
<style name="MyOwnRadioButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/myoptionradio</item>
</style>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppThemeCustom" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <!--<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>-->
    <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/MyOwnRadioButton</item>
</style>
```

this is my myoptionradio.xml in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/abs__ic_cab_done_holo_light" />
</selector>
```

and my xml is like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/exp_body"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/exp_body_friendly"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/exp_friendly_text" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/exp_body_none"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/exp_none_text" />
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

i have done nothing in my code and all works properly in lollipop and above devices with changed radio button
image but not work in kitkat and show default radio button in kitkat

thanks in advance

Comment: where did you change custom image

Comment: as you can see i declared MyOwnRadioButton in style and it takes myoptionradio as drawable and in that myoptionradio i take image where android:state_checked = "true"

Comment: then  set  style="@style/MyOwnRadioButton"   for RadioButtons

Comment: i already set it please see my style xml file where i declare <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/MyOwnRadioButton</item> and also i set those theme in manifest

Comment: just give a try

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: were is your  AppThemeCustom style inside values-v21 or values ?

Comment: my AppThemeCustom is in values folder and i said it works for all lollipop and above but not below kitkat so i thought that i shouldn't have to move it in values-21

Answer (score 0):

just remove `style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton`

style should be like this

```
 <style name="MyOwnRadioButton">
        <item name="android:button">@drawable/myoptionradio</item>
    </style>
```

and set style for `Radio button`

```
   <RadioButton
         ............
          ...........
         style="@style/MyOwnRadioButton"/>
```

Comment: Ok it works but what if i want this change in sub option menu where i grouped my submenu as radio button and i can not style it directly